# What is the significance of `flatmap` in SICP?

Tags: scheme, sicp, map-function, flatmap

```
(define (accumulate op initial sequence) 
  (if (null? sequence) 
   initial 
   (op (car sequence) 
     (accumulate op initial (cdr sequence))))) 
      
(define (flatmap proc seq) 
  (accumulate append nil (map proc seq)))
```

The above is a code snippet from SICP, in Scheme. Why is the `flatmap` procedure needed? What is the difference between `flatmap` and `map`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(map proc seq)` will apply `proc` to the sequence `seq`, returning one value for each element. It is possible for each such value to be another sequence.

`(accumulate append nil seq)` will use `append` to concatenate all copies of elements in `seq` into a new list.

Thus, `flatmap` will apply `proc` to all elements of `seq`, and produce a new *flattened* list with all the results. Conceptually, this is the difference of `map` and `flatmap` in other languages as well (Java, Scala, etc.), in that `map` produces one value for each element, while `flatmap` may produce multiple or none (thanks Chris).

For instance, in Clojure:

```
(map #(clojure.string/split  % #"\s+") ["two birds" "with one stone"])
;; => (["two" "birds"] ["with" "one" "stone"])

(mapcat #(clojure.string/split  % #"\s+") ["two birds" "with one stone"])
;; => ("two" "birds" "with" "one" "stone")
```

Comment: "... while flatmap may produce multiple":  For the benefit of the original poster, flatmap may also produce no value for an element, if the mapping procedure returns '().  You can implement filter using flatmap.